# QPropertyAnimation for rotating QWidget

Tags: qt, animation, rotation, qwidget, qpixmap

I'm new to Qt and I'm having some problem with `QWidget` rotation.

**I have a QPixmap inside a QLabel.
What I want is to animate it with a continuous rotation by 90 degrees.**

I know `QPropertyAnimation` and I know how to use it, but I'm struggling with How to use it for rotating a `QWidget`. Is there any simple way to use achieve my goal and rotate the entire `QLabel` or the `QPixmap` inside it with an animation?
Thank you.

Comment: `continuous rotation by 90 degrees` after rotated 90 degrees, repeat from 0? Or gives some delay then rotate continuously increase to 180 degrees?

Comment: Hi @Jiu. Forgot about the word "continuously". I need a rotation of the QLabel (or the QPixmap inside it) possibly with QPropertyAnimation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the demo for rotation of `QLabel/QPixmap` with animation.
it's not necessary to use `QPropertyAnimation`. Because there is no rotate property for `QLabel` or `QPixmap`. So used `QVariantAnimation` make `QPixmap` rotate as animation and use [QPixmap::transformed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#transformed) to rotate it. If you want well to control the animation of the pixmap, highly recommend [QGraphicsPixmapItem](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicspixmapitem.html) with `QPropertyAnimation`

```
class RotateMe : public QLabel {

    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit RotateMe(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR) :
        QLabel(parent),
        pixmap(100, 100),
        animation(new QVariantAnimation )
    {
        resize(200, 200);
        pixmap.fill(Qt::red);

        animation->setDuration(10000);
        animation->setStartValue(0.0f);
        animation->setEndValue(90.0f);
        connect(animation, &QVariantAnimation::valueChanged, [=](const QVariant &value){
            qDebug()<<value;
            QTransform t;
            t.rotate(value.toReal());
            setPixmap(pixmap.transformed(t));
        });
        animation->start();
    }
private:
    QPixmap             pixmap;
    QVariantAnimation  *animation;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Jiu this is a good working solution. Otherwise, as you suggested I subclassed the QGraphicsPixmapItem in order to have more control for rotation, movement, etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the rotation in two ways:

1) Create a collection of static images each of which represents the original pixmap rotated by some angle. With a timer you can change your label's pixmap with one from your collection. This will imitate the animated rotation.

2) Use a single pixmap and override your label's `QLabel::painEvent()` where you should rotate the `QPainter` object with `QPainter::rotate()` function each time you redraw the label.

Comment: About your second point, I should use a QTimer to redraw continuously the pixmap, isn't it?
I was thinking about to subclass the QLabel, add a new property called "angle" and use it with QPropertyAnimation. Could be a good idea?

Comment: Yes, you can implement it that way too.